# Do we have any mechanism for post logout activity on Client application using java servlet adaptor of Keycloak IDP?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, keycloak

In Keycloak SSO environment when java servlet adaptor is used, let us assume there are two Clients C1 and C2. When user performs a logout action on C2, IDP is supposed to make a callback to C1 *(admin url e.g. http://c1.com/keycloak )*. Now, If C1 needs to do some cleanup activity after keycloak api cleanup things are done, what are the means available to developers ? Is there any Event API available or some custom code needs to be written ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not get any updates on the question, however got it working after extending the keycloak servlet adapter for implementing event mechanisms for login and logout actions.